# How can we Force Databricks Structured Streaming to read data from event hubs every few seconds even if there is no new data?

Tags: azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

We are using Databricks structured streaming to read data from azure event hubs and we are using forEachBatch to upsert the data to a delta table in the writeStream part

The issue is - the events are not being written to delta tables as soon as they are available in the event hubs. Instead -  there is a varying delay which makes the data available at a lag in delta table. We already used **.trigger(processingTime=10 seconds)** but seems it is not helping much

Can we use some property at readStream/ writeStream to force the data read from the event hubs ?

Comment: @alexott - Could you please guide here ?

Comment: What connector are you using? EventHubs or Kafka?

Comment: Hi @alexott -we are using Eventhubs with AD authentication - using the AuthCallBack jar files on the cluster

Comment: you can do it now without need for a separate jar file:  https://alexott.blogspot.com/2023/10/delta-live-tables-recipes-consuming.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without looking into logs, seeing the configuration of EventHubs and Spark, etc. The `processingTime` triggers a new micro-batch for every specified period, but the previous micro-batch can still run and "block" your new micro-batch.

I observed something like with Spark connector for EventHubs where some executors stuck because specific EventHubs partitions were slow (it's even [documented](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/slow-partition-adjustment-feature.md) in their repo).

Another issue with the EventHubs connector is that it maps EventHubs partitions into Spark partitions 1:1. If you have a very low count of source partitions and more cluster cores, your cluster is underutilized. From that perspective, the Spark Kafka connector is much better because you can set the `minPartitions` property to the number of cores, and the data processing will be better parallelized. Plus, you get other benefits - the Kafka connector is shipped with Databricks Runtimes, so you don't need to install an extra library, you can use DLT ([example](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2022/06/delta-live-tables-recipes-consuming.html)), etc. You can also use AAD auth with Kafka connector - here is a [simple library that allows that](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/kafka-eventhubs-aad-auth). And since DBR 12.2 it's possible to use AD auth natively, as described in [this blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2023/10/delta-live-tables-recipes-consuming.html).